# Force proxy settings (Solaris\Linux)

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, solaris, firefox

I have tried the following from the command line in solaris:

```
 DATE TIME user@host> bash
 bash-3.2$ export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080/
 bash-3.2$ echo $http_proxy
 http://localhost:8080/
 bash-3.2$ firefox
```

Since I do not have a proxy running on localhost firefox should not be able to reach any website, however it acts as if no proxy is set.  I looked in preferences and use system proxy settings is checked, but there is no localhost:8080 filled in.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox won't use that environmental variable unless you first install the [Environmental Proxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/environment-proxy/) extension -- then it'll honor that variable just fine.

See also [this quesion on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23117/configuring-firefox-to-use-a-proxy-from-the-command-line) for more detailed information.

Comment: Then where does firefox get its "Use system proxy settings" from?

Comment: Depends on your environment. If you are running under Gnome it will get them from "gconf" (try `gconf-editor` and look in `/system/proxy`).